# Access an ArrayList inside a Java Map

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, dictionary, arraylist

This is the first question I've posted on this site!

In the final part of a Java assignment for university, my class has been asked to show we understand how to use different types of arrays.

At one point, we'll need to make and maintain a Map(key, value).
However, we'll need to use an ArrayList(String) as the Map's value.

Adding to this Map appears easy enough:
Just check that the Map in question does not already contain the specified key and then create the array with its values filled in and 'put' it, with the key String to the Map.

```
private Map<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

public void addToMap(String key, String value) {
  if (!this.map.containsKey(key) {
    ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
    array.add(value);
    this.map.put(key, array);
  }
  else {
    this.map.get(key).add(value); // Does this add a new item to the current ArrayList?
  }
}
```

But what if I wanted to edit the contents of that array?
I've only just started looking at Maps today, so I'm a little new to them, but I see they have a 'put' method - and I understand what put, pop and push are usually for, so this is slightly familiar.
Would I have to copy the contents of the array into a new temporary one, remove() the old "key => value" pair and make a new one with the additional data?

Your help is very appreciated! :D

Comment: That's not an array. It's an `ArrayList`. Is your assignment *actually* meant to be about arrays, or about collections in general?

Comment: You just do `map.get(key).add(element)`.

Comment: @JonSkeet : Sorry if I confused you. Yes, I do indeed know the basic differences between arrays and array-lists. I was using the general English term for 'collection of things', which just so happens to be "array". But anyway, I've updated my terminology now.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik you are violating [LoD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

Comment: @tintinmj I think you don't quite understand what I am talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Javadoc of [Map.#put](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put%28K,%20V%29)

> Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map
>   (optional operation). **If the map previously contained a mapping for
>   the key, the old value is replaced by the specified value**. (A map m is
>   said to contain a mapping for a key k if and only if m.containsKey(k)
>   would return true.)

So you can see that if you modify your `array`, you don't need to delete the pair. Just re-map it with the previous key.

And There is an syntactical error in your code. You can't instantiate an interface. So your code should be

```
private Map<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
```

or `TreeMap` or any direct concrete subclass of `Map` interface.

Comment: Updated my error - thanks for spotting that!
So I just need to get the reference of the ArrayList, update that and do a new .put() ?

Comment: Yes. Get the `key` of `ArrayList` value then update the `ArrayList` and simply re-map it.

Comment: @CindyStarfall No, you do not need a new `.put` (if you do it, it amounts to a no-op). You *only* need to update the arraylist of interest.

Comment: @CindyStarfall yes unless you're re-refering your arraylist you don't need a new `.put`.

Comment: What's "re-refering"? That's no standard term.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik `A a = new A(); a = new A(); //again`

Comment: I think the term you are looking for is "reassigning", although reassignment itself is not the salient concept here---it's *creating a new arraylist*, which would of course be the wrong thing to do.

Comment: So If I looked through the Map to find the key I'm looking for and use the getter for that key, could I affix an add() method on to the end of the getter to allow me to add to the same array? E.g:

    if (this.map.containsKey(key)) {
      this.map.get(key).add(value); // ArrayList updated?
    }

Comment: @CindyStarfall YES! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `Map` contains references to `ArrayList`s.

```
String key = "some list name";
// This assumes this entry is in the map; doesn't check for null
ArrayList<String> listInMap = map.get(key);
listInMap.add("new thing to add to list");
```

When you use `Map.get()` it returns the reference to the `ArrayList` in the map, not a copy of it. You can then modify that `List` via the returned reference.

Comment: I understand! Thanks! So the Map's getter gives me a reference, and when I do something with that reference (like adding an extra element), it'll update the place in memory where it's kept in the Map? So will I even need to do anything more to the specified index of that Map? Or just edit the object with the reference?

Comment: You're dealing with references (pointers). The `ArrayList` is an object on the heap. Any reference to that object can be used to mutate it. The code above is all you need to modify the `ArrayList` your map contains a reference to.

Answer (score 0):

To edit the contents of one particular arrayList you need first to get it from the map, and then just add / remove from the array:

```
ArrayList<String> list = map.get("key");
list.get(index);
list.add("something");
```